# I have problem in understanding how to write unit test for ng-idle core in my Application

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular8, ng-idle

I am using ng idle core in my Angular8 app to handle idle timeout scenario, I dont have clue how to write unit tests by setting a mock value for Idle. It would be helpful if anyone can assist me by giving a plunkr example or sharing the code snippet. Thanks

Comment: not related to protractor